# How to extract data of LONG RAW and reinsert to other db?

Tags: oracle

I have a task to write a PL/SQL script for converting LONG RAW columns to BLOB. I ask the DBA to extract a sample data for LONG RAW (I want to test with real data) and I will re-insert this sample to my table. The DBA extracted 1 row to insert script, I tried with PL/SQL developer tool but I received error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long.
```

And the content of LONG RAW data so long and have format:

```
'D0CF11E0A1B11AE1000000000000000000000000000000003E000300FEFF09000600000000000...'
```

Do we have some solution to extract LONG RAW data and move it to other database?

Thank you.